# Create a DataFrame with nested structure and populate data from input table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark in Scala and want to transform an existing dataset (dataframe) to a new table which will contain nested structure.

Example input:
columnA columnB columnC columnD columnE

Example output:
columnA columnB columnC columnF:{columnD, columnE} (create a new column that contains both D and E as nested structure)

It's straightforward to transform columnA-C as I can use `.withColumn()`, but I am not sure how to specify a new nested column structure and populate data from same table. I think `StructType(Array(StructField1, StructField2))` is needed to define nested schema, how do I combine a StructType with "regular" column and insert data?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spark verion 3.1.1, then there is a new API `withField` introduced in `Column` class.

You can use it as

```
dataframe
    .withColumn("ColumnF",$"ColumnF".withField("ColumnA",$"ColumnA")
    .withColumn("ColumnF",$"ColumnF".withField("ColumnE",$"ColumnE")
```

Make sure to import scala implicits.

For the older verions of Spark you could leverage `struct` function as:

```
dataframe
    .withColumn("ColumnF",struct($"ColumnF.*", $"ColumnA")
    .withColumn("ColumnF",struct($"ColumnF.*",$"ColumnE")
```

Comment: To confirm, the effect of following query will transform input:
{a,b,e,d}
to output:
{A,b,f:{d,e}} ?

output=spark.table("input")
    .withColumnRenamed("a", "A")
    .withColumn("b")
    .withColumn("f", struct($"f.*", $"d"))
    .withColumn("f", struct($"f.*", $"e"))

Comment: Here your withColumn("b") is wrong. 'withColumn' function accepts 2 parameters (column_name,Column). If you want to add a new column "b" then you also need to specify the "value" for that column which is of "Column" type.